# Am i doing the right test? does this hypothesis make sense?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

My study is investigating the effect of 6 IV's on a categorical DV (yes/no- yes is coded as a higher score i.e 2) in 2 countries to see which of these IV's is a most important in predicting the DV in each country. A logistic regression stratified for each country shows me some variables had an effect (i.e predicted) the DV in one country but not the other. 
However, a independent samples t test showed me one of the country's had a significantly higher scores on the 6 IV's than the other (disregarding the DV here)

For my hypotheisis, how should i pose my research questions

should it be like this...

1. a higher score on these 6 IVs will predict the DV (yes) - without indicating a differences between the 2 countries as my logistic regression was not comparable as i had to stratify it for each country seperatley.
2. Overall country X will score higher than country Y on all the IV's.
3. Country X will have more respondents reporting yes (to the DV)

i am very confused on how to link this all together, i would appreciate if you could take the time to understand the study and the findings to help me phrase my hypothesis correctly.

Comment: I removed the plea for help, since they tend to summon the downvote faeries. You're asking for free help on the internet -- someone will answer your question if and when they're interested in doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking at, but you indeed can pose your research questions as follows:

1. What's effect of the IV's on the DV in *a* or *both* countries? (this is the "regression/measuring effects" type of statistical analysis). (your question 1)
2. Is there some difference in scores between the countries? (the "measuring of difference" type of statistical analysis). (your question 2&3)

E.g. a t-test and a regression analysis adress, by its nature, different type of statistical questions; they can however be linked by doing the following:

Perform a regression analysis on **all** the data and let the country type also be a IV, then you can measure the effect of respectively all the original IV's and the "country variable" and you can for example check what's the difference between scores per country (same research question as you 2&3 and the same type of analysis as a t-test) and questions like whether the country in itself has more influence on the score than one/all/some subset of the original IV's.

Comment: I would like to clarify my QS, thank you for the advice, 

A logistic regression each country shows which IV's are predicting the outcome variable - whether respondents take a certain medication or not (answered yes or no). 
A chi2 analysis will show me which country (x or y) is more likely to have said yes, they do take this medication (thus showing a significant differences between the 2 countries).

But  is it important to predict that country X will have a higher score on the 6 IV's, hence why it was more likely to they said yes to taking medication?

Comment: I don't know for sure if your last sentence is a question for me? In case you would like to measure and compare the effects of *both* the country and the IV's; then yes, you have to add the country as a categorical variable. In case your question was to say whether there is a link between the Chi-square/T-test (difference between DV's) and the regression analysis (difference in effect between the IV's) by knowing the fact that the IV's on country Y are higher than country X and there ís some positive correlation between the IV and the DV, then yes: the DV of country Y will be higher...

Comment: Thank you! So in your opinion would you say it is a good idea to state my prediction of a higher score in all IV's for Country Y as a seperate hypothesis and then report the T test result which has confirmed this? but don't link it explicitly to the DV for this question?

Comment: Yes I think so, it seems likely to me that if you let the country be a categorical variable you can measure the difference between the effect of the country and the IVs and if you want to test the overall difference in scores between the countries you just have to apply the chi-square/t-test. Also if you want to test the differences over all IVs between the countries, I'll just apply 6 t-tests OR (if there is a positive correlation between IV and DV) logically conclude that the IVs of Y are higher because the DV of Y is higher.

Comment: You have no idea how much you have helped! Much appreciated